# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined at fs.js:51:5 in Node v15.7.0

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have installed Node version v15.7.0.

> gulp -v
> CLI version: 2.3.0
> Local version: 4.0.2
>
> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
> at fs.js:51:5
> at req_ (D:\mohan\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
> at Object.req [as require] (D:\mohan\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
> at Object. (D:\mohan\node_modules\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)

Answer (score 0):

We don't support node 15, it's an unstable release. I have no idea if graceful-fs works with 16

Please check below link.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2625